# Change date format in a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON file with multiple entries similar to the one below

```
[
 {
  "timestamp": "7/8/2021",
  "parent": "/develop-life-skills/",
  "name": "Markus",
  "comment": "Lorem ipsum dola sit amet.",
  "isAuthor": false
  }
]
```

Would anyone advise me on how to convert the timestamp from `m/d/yyyy` to a format of `yyyy-mm-dd`?

Comment: The input date format is ambiguous between d/m/yyyy and m/d/yyyy, you need to know which it's in before being able to accurately convert it.

Answer (score 0):

I would take that data, throw it into a script that uses `JSON.parse(data)` and maps over that data to update the value accordingly. Using a library like [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/v2.28.0/docs/format) is what I'd reach for.

```js
import {format} from 'date-fns';

const data = [
 {
  "timestamp": "7/8/2021",
  "parent": "/develop-life-skills/",
  "name": "Markus",
  "comment": "Lorem ipsum dola sit amet.",
  "isAuthor": false
  }
];

const formattedData = JSON.parse(data).map(item => {
  const itemWithNewDateFormat = {
    ...item,
    timestamp: format(new Date(item.timestamp), 'yyyy-mm-dd')
  }

  return itemWithNewDateFormat;
});

// You could then stringify with JSON.stringify(formattedData)
```

Comment: Is that date formatted as m/d/yyyy or d/m/yyyy? What you have assume that it's m/d/yyyy

Comment: Also, `data` is a JS object not JSON, parsing it won't work as you have it.

Answer (score 0):

try this, if you use map funciton, it will create another array, this code updates existed one

```
var json=...your obj;

json.forEach((item) => {
  var arr = item.timestamp.split("/");
  item.timestamp = `${arr[2]}-${arr[0].padStart(2,"0")}-${arr[1].padStart(2,"0")}`;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built-in toLocateDateString()...

```
let formattedDate = new Date(item.timestamp).toLocaleDateString('en-CA', { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' });
```